# Caching huge data in Process memory

Tags: c++

I am working in Finance Industry. We want to roll out Database hit for data processing. It is very costly. So we are planning to go for on-demand cache logic. [ runtime insert & runtime lookup ]

Is anyone worked in implementation of Caching logic for more than 10 million of records?. Per record is say about 160 - 200 bytes.

I faced following disadvantages with different approach.

1. Can not use **stl std::map** to implement a key base cache registry.
   The insert and lookup is very slow after 200000 records.
2. **Shared memory or memory mapped** files are kind of overhead for caching data,
   because these data are not shared across the processes
3. Use of **sqlite3** in-memory & flatfile application database can be
   worth. But it too  have slow lookup after a 2-3 million of records.
4. Process memory might have some limitation on its own kernel memory consumption. my 
   assumption is 2 gig on 32 bit machine & 4 gig on 64 bit machine.

Please suggest me something if you had come across this problem and solved by any means.

Thanks

Comment: DB indexes are usually implemented through BTrees, not std::map (R&B binary trees). BTrees are much more effective for the scales you're talking about.

Comment: You can use both shared memory and memory mapped files between processes. At least on linux. What OS are you using?

Comment: Is this a key-value store or something more complex?

Comment: How about `std::unordered_map`? Expected O(1) lookup time if your key can be hashed well.

Comment: @YI_H....We are using solaris platform. It is just a key value store. Just to store and retrive data. We do complex caculation after retreiving data from store.

Comment: @Kerrek.... for std::unordered_map. lookup may be O(1) constant time. Insertion is still slower in case of more collisions. key is not a simple key. It is a composite key. Its a structure OrderKey with overloaded == & < operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your cache is a simple key-value store, you should not be using `std::map`, which has *O*(log *n*) lookup, but `std::unordered_map`, which has *O*(1) lookup.  You should only use `std::map` if you require sorting.

It sounds like performance is what you're after, so you might want to look at [Boost Intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/intrusive.html).  You can easily combine `unordered_map` and `list` to create a high-efficiency LRU.

Answer (score 1):

Read everything into memory and create R&B tree for key access.

http://www.mit.edu/~emin/source_code/cpp_trees/index.html

In one recent project, we had database with some 10s M records, and were using such strategy.

Your data weight is 2GB, from your post.  With overhead, it will come up to say double.  It's no problem for any 64bit architecture.

Comment: @Daniel.... std::map internally uses Red Black trees only. also the data is not available at once. Cache grows exponentially over the time. In the morning it may not have records but on day close, It might have 10 mill of records.

Comment: What times do you need for Read and Insert?  Also, do you need some kind of iterator?

Comment: Also consider this: insert time is not important, as it will be eaten because the data will come from the 'outside' so fetch will be slow anyway.  So you need to focus on reads.  I believe you that std::map uses RB trees, but I know that our implementation returned 1000 records from our data structure in few microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently changed the memory allocation of our product (3D medical volume viewer) to use good old memory mapped files.

The advantages were:

- I can allocate all physical RAM if I like (my 32 bit app sometimes needs more than 4 gig on a 64 bit machine)
- If you map only portions, your adress space is largely free for your application to use, which improves reliability.
- if you run out of memory, things just slow down, no crashes.

In my case it was just data (mostly readonly). If you have a more complex data structure, this will be more work than using "normal" objects.

You can actually share these across processes (if they're backed by a real file). This may behave differently, I dont have experience with that.