# Simple C/C++ in-process cache similar to memcached

Tags: c, caching

I need a simple (LRU) cache which should run in-process. I found memcached, which looks great but there does not seem to be an easy way to host it in-process. I don't need a distributed cache, just a simple key/value store and some kind of LRU behaviour and some nice allocator to limit fragmentation, as the entry size varies a lot (few bytes -- few kilobytes.) There must be surely an existing implementation of such a thing? Should be C or C++.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668824/caching-huge-data-in-process-memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hate to answer this way, but it would be fairly simple to implement yourself.

1. Allocator.  Use `malloc` and `free`.  They *do* work, and they work well.  This also makes it easier to interface with the rest of your program.
2. Mutex -> hash table, tree, or trie.  You can use a linked list to track LRU.  Don't try to do fancy lockless stuff.

Should weigh less than a couple hundred lines, knock it out in a good solid day.

Comment: I don't believe there will be a better answer anytime soon; and yes, the simple hand-written LRU does work for now. I'm still curious to hear about a better key/value store though ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using [commoncache](http://code.google.com/p/commoncache/) but the project doesn't appear to have any activity and issues raised (with patches) by my colleague are still unaddressed...